# How to achieve organisation of test suites and cases with Boost?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

### Preface

I'm new to Unit Testing and rather new to C++. Recently I had some experience with test driven development in Ruby using RSpec. Now I'm trying getting similar working in C++ with Boost's unit testing framework.

### Scenario

I'm organising my header and source files of the application in a directory `/src` under the project's root folder. As I've seen it multiple times around in other C++ programs, having the tests in a directory `/tests` in the project's root directory seems reasonable.

Now I want to replicate the directory structure of the source files as well in the tests. Thus, assume I've got the following source/header file structure:

```
/src
  /controller
    controller_class.h
    controller_class.cpp
  /model
    model_a.h
    model_a.cpp
    model_b.h
    model_b.cpp
  /view
    simple_view.h
    simple_view.cpp
```

And thus the tests are organised as followed

```
/tests
  TestRunner.cpp
  /controller
    controller_class_test.cpp
  /model
    model_a_test.cpp
    model_b_test.cpp
  /view
    simple_view_test.cpp
```

For the `TestRunner.cpp` I took the example from [this blog post](http://www.sharprobotica.com/2010/04/including-boost-test-in-your-c-project/):

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "MyProgram Unit Tests"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

### Problem

I now thought to continue in `TestRunner.cpp` with the creation of the basic test suits (for controller, model and view) as follows

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( controller )
  //some stuff here
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( model )
  //some stuff here
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE ( view )
  //some stuff here
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

### Desire

But how can I now integrate further nested test suites and cases into these top-level test suits? I finally want to have the actual test cases only appear in the `*_test.cpp` files. While each of those files wrap the test cases into one additional test suite:

- Master Test Module (`TestRunner.cpp`)

  - Controller Test Suite (`TestRunner.cpp`)

    - Controller Class Test Suite (`controller_class_test.cpp`)

      - Controller Class Test Cases (`controller_class_test.cpp`)
  - Model Test Suite (`TestRunner.cpp`)

    - Model A Test Suite (`model_a_test.cpp`)

      - Model A Test Cases (`model_a_test.cpp`)
    - Model B Test Suite (`model_b_test.cpp`)

      - Model B Test Cases (`model_B_test.cpp`)
  - View Test Suite (`TestRunner.cpp`)

    - Simple View Test Suite (`simple_view_test.cpp`)

      - Simple View Test Cases (`simple_view_test.cpp`)

### Question

How do I have to include the nested suits and cases in the respective higher level suite? I could not find anything in the Boost documentation, though [The Unit Test Framework > User's guide > Test organization > Test suite > Automated registration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/auto-test-suite.html) came pretty close.
In Ruby with RSpec one just needs to place the test files (read: `*_spec.rb`) the way I did and its automatically iterating through them. I guess, with Boost I have to explicitly declare it that way.

Comment: I've found [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/wiki) to be far easier and more elegant to use than Boost.Test. You may want to have a look. :)

Comment: @jalf Thanks for the hint. I'll have a closer look at that. Though I'll use some other Boost libraries for my project, I guess, Boost.Test is easier to integrate.

Comment: Not really. Catch is a single header you include, and you're done. Boost.Test is much bigger, and requires you to link to a library. I use other boost libs too, but I still find it easier to use Catch than Boost.Test.

Comment: Boost.Test does not require you to link with the library. There is also one header option as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.Test test suites are similar to C++ namespaces. You can restart them any time. Each of your test files just need to place test cases in correct test suites:

```
controller_class_a_test.cpp:

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( controller )

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_class_a )
 {
 }

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()


controller_class_b_test.cpp:

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( controller )

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_class_b )
 {
 }

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

The same concept applies to the test tree of any depth. Also you do not need top level TestRunner.cpp at all. Just combine all your test files into a single test module and Boost.Test will take care about the rest.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Seems working :-) And I'm kind of proud, that I finally got it set up with CMake. *yeah* Awesome day.