# How to include source file into Bool.Test case from other directory tree?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, cmake

This is somehow a follow-up question to my previous one: [How to achieve organisation of test suites and cases with Boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9302777/588243)

The directory structure is as stated in the other question and I'm following the therein described organisation of the Boost.Test cases as well.

However, I'm struggling with getting everything to work with CMake.

My `tests/CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
# tests/CMakeLists.txt
# Add the test sources
set(test_SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/TestRunner.cpp)

# Add test cases
add_subdirectory(model)

# Include Boost and program's sources (find_package has been executed before)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Create the tests
add_executable(MyProgramTests ${test_SOURCES})

# Link agains Boost libraries
target_link_libraries(MyProgramTests ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

and `tests/model/CMakeLists.txt` says:

```
# tests/model/CMakeLists.txt
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model/CMakeLists.txt)

# Add test cases to the list
set(test_SOURCES
  ${test_SOURCES}
  ${model_SOURCES}
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/model/model_a_test.cpp
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

In `src/model/CMakeLists.txt` I've just written:

```
set(model_SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model/model_a.cpp)
```

How do I have to include the `src/model/model_a.cpp` in my `tests/model/model_a_test.cpp` so the compiled finally finds it? I tried with `#include "src/model/model_a.cpp"`, `#include "model/model_a.cpp"` and even just `#include "model_a.cpp"`. In all cases the `model_a.cpp` could not be found.

I'm pretty sure, I'm missing something in the CMakeLists files. But what?

### Edit

I finally solved it by adding the program's source directory `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model` to the `include_directories` command in `tests/CMakeLists.txt`. With this, `#include "model_a.cpp"` should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `PARENT_SCOPE` in order to bring the value of `${model_SOURCES}` up from `src/model/CMakeLists.txt` into `tests/model/CMakeLists.txt`

Try using

```
set(model_SOURCES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/model/model_a.cpp PARENT_SCOPE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that did not helped. But by fiddling around with your solution, I tried what I described in the edit of my question. As your answer led me to rethink the way I'm including my sources, I'll accept your answer.